# How to make a div pop out with parent div having overflow hidden and position absolute

Tags: css

Trying to add a tooltip to a div with position:absolute and overflow hidden.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qH5nHheCoyOmvRKLVx2o?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        Why am I not overlapping?
    </div>
</div>

.container{
height:300px;
width:300px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
background-color:black;
color: blue;    
}

.inner{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: right;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: It *is* overlapping. You have `overflow: hidden` set for `.container`, which is why you cannot see the rest of `.inner` div.

Comment: I know that.But i want to show a tooltip even though the parent has overflow:hidden.So need a work around for that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past and couldn't find a solution except maybe for hacks. I ended with adding the inner div to an element higher in the DOM tree and positioning using Javascript.